Energies from single points vs. AIMD for training Machine Learning Force Fields
I am currently training a force field using machine learning techniques. One way to test the performance of the ML model is to use the force field for a production run (= molecular dynamics) and taking snapshots. For each snapshot a single point calculation (=DFT) should be performed. Then energies, forces and stresses are compared from single-point calculation and the MD run.
The MD run is at finite temperature and I think this has an impact on the total energy of the system. However, single point calculations are at zero temperature. 
How to compare the total energies then?
Maybe I miss a point about single point calculations. I am doing them in VASP by setting IBRION = -1 , NSW = 0 . I think a temperature cannot be set up for a single point calculation?

You are mixing things. If you take snapshots you are effectively "stopping" the simulation. Per se, MD simulations are simply a chain of singlepoints where you have an algorithm in-between which decides where atoms should go, the temperature you set will affect this algorithm (strongly), but will not affect how VASP calculate things.
You should compare the potential energy of your MD simulation with the total energy of DFT. Forces should be comparable

@Okano Thanks for the quick comment. So what is the potential energy of the MD simulation ? If I have e.g. a simulation with 10000 steps, i can take up to 10000 snapshots, where each snapshot containts a total energy and forces (on each atom). I conclude from your statement, that energies, forces from snapshots should be comparable to single point calculation, because the temperature only has an impact on the algorithm for moving the atoms ?

This is related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10102/4515
I will write up a proper answer in a couple of hours

In the shortest way possible, temperature cannot be defined for single-point calculations. This is because temperature arises from the kinetic energies of the atoms or ions (nuclei), and a single-point calculation does not account for those. In VASP, they will be set to zero.
More subtly for training ML force fields, another difference between taking single-point calculations versus straight-up AIMD frames is that AIMD uses the electron density from the preceding time-step to begin computing the next step's electron density. So if a frame taken for a single-point calculation is  in some way complex to converge, or unusual, then a single-point calculation may become quite long or tricky. This difference (plus possible Pulay stresses) motivates tight convergence criteria for DFT calculations used for training ML. If the convergence criteria are stringent enough*, then I think taking AIMD frames without extra relaxation is passable. However, an alternative is running lower-resolution MD for broader sampling of diverse local environments before improving resolution on select single-points for training data.
*- your mileage may vary, but for me in VASP PREC = Accurate and 10^-6 eV energy convergence has been sufficient.
Related question: Discrepancy in forces between AIMD and relaxation

Thanks! For information, I use EDIFF = 10^-6 and PREC = Accurate, but Gamma-Point only due to large supercell ( around 200 atoms) . In my case, energy from SP- calculation differs about 10eV from MD snapshot. This could indicate, that the quality of the force field is bad and needs more training. However, I am not sure, how to find the right origin for the deviation in forces /energies. What do you recommend for ALGO ? I currently use ALGO = fast.

The 10 eV are most likely the kinetic energy. It does not go into the training of your MLFF, because it depends on velocities and single-points do not have that information. Only the potential energy and strain tensor go into the training.

I tested a few ALGOs and they did not matter for me. If you worry about it, test it.

Your mileage may vary, but also if you're looking for stability in NPT for your end-use MLFF, I would reduce the size of the training cells. This is because smaller cells sample the stress tensor more widely than larger cells. I tested this, and my MLFFs from 32-atom cells were not substantively different from those trained on 64-atom cells or on 128-atom cells or on 128-atom cells at Gamma point. But the 32-atom trained ones were a lot more stable, and I did not have to go to the Gamma point. Win-win.

Other possible origins for order of 10 eV differences in energies: magnetic moments, or the single-point ending up in some metastable state because it does not start with the preceding step's electronic wavefunctions.

What do you mean by "kinetic energy does not go into the training" ? Does this imply that total energy from AIMD step does not have to be comparable to SP calculation since the kinetic energy is included in AIMD ? If so, is there a way to substract the kinetic energy term such that I can compare the values? Thank you btw for your advice so far.

@Lukas Please ask follow-up questions in new posts. If you're asking what someone "means" by something, then okay, you can ask it in a comment, but the question: "If so, is there a way to subtract the kinetic energy term..." needs to be asked in a new post if Andrey says "Yes". On MMSE.Meta, the "one question per post" rule is mentioned, and has received agreement from everyone that has voted or commented on it so far.

@Lukas "kinetic energy does not go into the training" means that information about atomic velocities information in structures that the ML is training on or in common ML frameworks. This is because the goal of MLFFs is to predict (potential) energy and forces from atomic positions. Velocities would only be relevant for training something like a Langevin viscosity term or memory kernel, which to my knowledge is never done. For all intents and purposes, yes, the total energies of AIMD and SP do not have to be equal, but potential energies should be.

@Lukas even if you take frames from AIMD, potential energy is what gets written to something like extxyz automatically. For example each ase.Atoms object created from an AIMD trajectory frame has a get_potential_energy() method and that is what gets written out.

@Lukas You might want to learn more about computational chemistry and MD simulations before training your own ML potential
